# Debugging service test client: Netbeans debugger won't recognize Glassfish server

Tags: java, debugging, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Did a fresh build of project (web service project).
2. Redeployed project war file to Glassfish server.
3. Restarted server with --debug=true.
4. Attached debugger from Netbeans.

Debugger attaches to the server without an error (responds "User Program Running"), however the Debug tab (in the Projects/Files/Services window) with all the different services that are supposed to get attached fails to show up as it did when everything was working.

When I try to start debugging the project, the server dropdown doesn't have any servers in it, and it won't let me start debugging without selecting a server.

Glassfish version is 2.1.1.  Netbeans version is 7.4 Patch 3.  JRE version is 1.7.0_79-b15.

I'm a bit of a Netbeans newbie, so I apologize if I've left out any information that's important.  Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional information relevant to the problem is that I was trying to get a test client working for the service.  The problem turned out to be that I was simply adding another java class to the service package.  The solution is:

1. Create a new project.
2. Add a new Web Service Client to the project (right click on the project, select New, etc.)
3. Run through the resulting wizard.
4. Add a package to the project.
5. Put your client code file in the package.

Netbeans will then fix up all the code with the necessary metadata and so on, and I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the netbeans,jdk and glassfish server are installed in the same folder
Program Files(x86)  or Program Files.If not then re-install them.
I use netbeans 7.0.1 ,glassfish 3.1.1 and jdk 1.7 and it runs fine.

If your problem is something else if I am not clear with your question, look at this
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195166

Comment: They're not in the same folder, but I've been able to debug properly with the folder structure that I have in place.  So, I'm skeptical that this would solve the problem.